# integer too large case with java netbeans Jcombobox

Tags: java, netbeans

Code in use

```
int angka =  Integer.valueOf(combo_dari.getSelectedItem().toString());
if (angka == 0740000 && angka < **0900000**)
```

Comment: i got the error for Integer Too Large 0900000, please help with my code above

Comment: A leading `0` in a numeric literal means Octal notation. Remove this `0` if you didn't mean to use octal there. Also what is the value you typed in the combobox ?

Comment: i cant bro, is there another way without remove the 0 ?

Comment: its 0900000 in the combobox

Comment: you are missing the point. You cannot add constraint and expect solution based on that. That is not a solution. Also your question does not have much description as to why the constraint is there.

Comment: `9` isn't a valid digit in an octal representation anyway. Also if all the values in the combobox start with `0`, use `combo_dari.getSelectedItem().toString().substring(1)` to get rid of it .

Comment: Just use `angka == 740000 && angka < 900000` Note the right term does not make any sense!

Comment: The if statement will only return true if angka == 0740000

Comment: i cant remove the 0 because the 0 before 9 is the unique code for the system

Comment: The added condition **angka < 0900000** is meaningless. You if clause condition **(angka == 0740000 && angka < 0900000)** is equivalent to **(angka == 0740000 )**.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can do something like:

```
Long newAngka =  Long.parseLong(combo_dari.getSelectedItem().toString());
if (newAngka == 740000L)
...
```

Then in the if statement you can cast to int the variable:

```
int angka = (int) newAngka;
```

Or in Java 8:

```
int angka = Math.toIntExact(newAngka);
```